# bad magic number in superblock

Tags: backup, superblock

I need to restore a broken partition superblock, so I get my list of backuped superblocks with :

```
sudo mke2fs -n /dev/sdd1
```

And I would like to know if when choosing the one to restore, if this is relevant to take the most recent one and if yes, which one is it ? The first one at 32768 or the last in list the : 214990848 ?

Comment: they should all be the same.  if you find that the one at 32768 is corrupt, try the next one, and continue until you find one that works.  if they all seem corrupt, verify you are working with the correct block size.

Comment: Thanks. Maybe you should put that in answer no ? So I can approve it. ;)

Comment: Reposted as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The superblock and backup superblocks should all be the same. Sometimes the backups can be corrupted just like the superblock, though, so if you find that the one at 32768 is corrupt, try the next one, and continue until you find one that works. if they all seem corrupt, verify you are working with the correct block size.